# Logical Operations Pattern using NOT

Tags: logical-operators

I have some tricky question encountered on an technical exam, hope I can get an output here

In which of the following statement(s) is(are) equivalent to the condition a AND (b OR c)

a.  NOT(NOT a OR NOT b) OR NOT (NOT a OR NOT c)

b.  NOT(NOT a OR (NOT b AND NOT c))

c.  NOT(NOT a OR NOT b) AND (NOT a OR NOT c)

d.  (NOT a AND NOT b) OR NOT c

My question, if the equation is

NOT a OR NOT b

Does it give a result b or a is acceptable since it uses OR?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to write a truth table.
OK, you might be a super-logician and break these down in your head,
but the interviewer is expecting you to draw a truth table for each of the 4 parts and say which final column matches.
So your first 3 columns are a,b,c, then some intermediate columns, then a result column.
All that matters is if the result columns match.

Answer (score 0):

A truth table is probably what the instructor/interviewer is looking for. However, there is a nice relationship that can quickly be used (with some practice) to find an answer in your head.

```
        a AND b = NOT ( NOT a OR NOT b )
```

Conversely,

```
        a OR b = NOT ( NOT a AND NOT b )
```

Applying this to your original problem,

```
        a AND ( b OR c ) = NOT ( NOT a OR NOT ( b OR c ) )
                         = NOT ( NOT a OR ( NOT b AND NOT c ) )
```

which is answer (b) in your example. Which is not to say that (b) is the ONLY correct answer, but it is ONE correct answer.